# Waving flag in openGL (C)

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to make a waving New Zealand flag using openGL and c (or c++),
i made the flag using a matrix but i dont know how to make the wave effect,
here is my whole code, i tried changing the parameters of the matrix in the idle function but i cant make the effect (it changes my whole flag to other shades which I am changing there:

```
#include "GLUT.H"
#include <math.h>

#define HEIGHT 600
#define WIDTH 600

unsigned char matrix[HEIGHT][WIDTH][3]; // r,g,b
double offset=0;

void init()
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<200;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j][0] = 0; // red
            matrix[i][j][1] = 255; // green
            matrix[i][j][2] = 0; // blue
        }

    for(i=200;i<400;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j][0] = 255; // red
            matrix[i][j][1] = 255; // green
            matrix[i][j][2] = 255; // blue
        }

    for(i=400;i<600;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j][0] = 0; // red
            matrix[i][j][1] = 0; // green
            matrix[i][j][2] = 255; // blue
        }

    glClearColor(0,0,0.4,0);
    glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawPixels(WIDTH,HEIGHT,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,matrix);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle()
{
    int i,j;
    double dist;
    offset-=0.14;

    for(i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            dist = sqrt((double)(i-HEIGHT/2)*(i-HEIGHT/2)+(j-WIDTH/2)*(j-WIDTH/2));
            //matrix[i][j][0] = 0;//int(255*(1+sin((2*j)*0.03+offset))/2); // red
            //matrix[i][j][1] = dist;//int(255*(1+sin((2*dist)*0.03+offset))/2); // green
            //matrix[i][j][2] = 0;//int(255*(1+sin((j)*0.03+offset))/2); // blue
        }


    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("ok");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Any ideas\suggestions\solution(lol) how i can make it wave?

p.s: I will need to add some star to it in middle also (also clueless how to draw it so it will wave)

Comment: Can you display the rectangle? Can you display it at an angle (from the camera)? Can you display it statically in a sine-wave pattern? Take step by step to achieve the last, then you're only one step away from actually animating the flag.

Comment: I can display the flag statically right now.

Comment: Then try and show the flag distorted using some kind of sine-wave, statically (i.e. not animated) along the Y-axis. Then the last step is to get that "distortion" to become animated, by adjusting the sine-wave effect in your `idle` function. To be honest I've never done it before myself, but that's how I would do it.

Comment: yeah, i tried that but i cant make the colors right

Comment: @Coder123: A waving flag is about vertex positions (and normals), not colors.

Comment: can you maybe point me how can i make the possitions so they will fit my flag?

Comment: Done properly, you would not have to bother about the colors. Thinking a little about it I was wrong with my previous comment: If I would do something like this, I would do it in a vertex shader, modulating the *z* axis of the *object* in a sine wave. Then I would just let normal shadow and lighting handle the lightening/darkening areas of the flag. But like I said, I haven't done this personally, there might be better ways of handling this.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with colors, making some of them darker, something like that (sorry beucause it's a spagetti code, you will have to adjust and optimize it):

```
void idle()
{
    static float count = 0.0;

    int i,j;
    count += 0.05;
    offset-=0.14;

    for(i=0;i<200;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j][0] = 0; // red
            matrix[i][j][1] = 200 + 55 * sin(count + j * 0.02); // green
            matrix[i][j][2] = 0; // blue
        }

    for(i=200;i<400;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j][0] = 200 + 55 * sin(count + j * 0.02); // red
            matrix[i][j][1] = 200 + 55 * sin(count + j * 0.02); // green
            matrix[i][j][2] = 200 + 55 * sin(count + j * 0.02); // blue
        }

    for(i=400;i<600;i++)
        for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j][0] = 0; // red
            matrix[i][j][1] = 0; // green
            matrix[i][j][2] = 200 + 55 * sin(count + j * 0.02); // blue
        }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```